# Can`t get song duration

Tags: c#, xna

I made a media player app, but i can`t get song duration.

```
Uri uriStreaming = new Uri("file://C:/a.mp3");
Song song = Song.FromUri("Song Name", uriStreaming);                       
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
myString = song.Duration.ToString();
SpriteBatch.DrawString(myfont, myString, stringLocation, myColor);
```

The string drawn shows 0:00:00 in case of any song. Any advice?
Later edit: if the song is loaded via Content.Load() method, everything is right, but i really need to load songs from file.

Comment: Good formatting is your friend..

Comment: i tried it with 2 songs, one of them played well, the other one didn`t even play. They have the same bitrate if it matters.

Comment: Now i found out that the songs selected from a specific album are not played, one randomly downloaded from zippyshare plays, but song duration is still 0:00:00